# How to view Google HTTP load balancer access logs without Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

I would like to see GCE HTTP/HTTPS Load Balancer access logs. By default, access logs go to Stackdriver. But we have to [exclude](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) the log named “cloud-http-load-balancer” because Stackdriver [will start charging on March 31, 2018](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/release-notes), and Stackdriver logs are [obscenely expensive](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing) ($0.50/GiB, and we get many TiB per month so it would be over $10,000/month).

How can we get Cloud Load Balancer access logs, but without Stackdriver? In comparison, AWS allows you to setup ELB to [export access logs to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) for no added charge other than the price of S3 itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log entries excluded from Stackdriver Logging will not appear in the Logs Viewer, logs-based metrics, or Stackdriver Error Reporting. The answer is in the same document you provided, as these future logs can still be exported before they are excluded, using [log sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exporting_excluded_logs). You could also use an [advance filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) to only exclude some of the load balancer logs (as request logs, then you would still be able to see warnings for example)